# $h^3$ term in probability density function of ideal gas

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, probability, phase-space, partition-function

Other than that we need the $h^3$ to 1) make the units correct and to 2) account for the normalization of the probability distribution, what interpretation can we give to this $h^3$ term in

\begin{align}
p(E_i) = \frac{1}{Z_1 h^3}\exp(-\beta E_i) \ ,
\end{align}
with 1-molecule partition function $Z_1 = \frac{1}{h^{3}} \int_\mathbb{R^3} \int_\mathbb{R^3} \exp \Big(-\beta\frac{p^2}{2m}\Big) \ \mathrm{d\mathbf{r}} \ \mathrm{d\mathbf{p}} $ and energy $E_i$ of microstate $i$.

Namely, if the partition function is defined to be the normalization constant for obtaining the probability distribution over the microstate energies, how did the situation arise that we need to *correct for the units*?

My confusion lies in the following. $Z_1$ represents the total number of microstates of a single molecule, were we have used $h^3$ to denote the phase-space volume of a single state. The naive guess would then be to assume that the probability distribution of a microstate $i$ would then be given by 
\begin{align}
p(E_i) = \frac{1}{Z_1}\exp(-\beta E_i).
\end{align}

That is, without the $h^3$ factor explicitly appearing in the probability distribution.

Is there no better explanation for the appearence of the $h^3$ factor in $p$ other than that we need to cancel out the $h^3$ factor in $Z_1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct expression is

$$p(\mathbf p ,\mathbf q)= \frac{e^{-\beta H}}{\int \int d \mathbf p d \mathbf q \ e^{-\beta H}}$$

since the integral of this is $1$.

But you would also like to write $Z$ as a dimensionless quantity, since it should represent the number of microstates. Since the integral

$$\int \int d \mathbf p d \mathbf q \ e^{-\beta H}$$

has the dimension of action cube, you need a quantity with the dimension of action cube to make it dimensionless. You therefore define $Z$ as

$$Z \equiv \frac 1 {h^3} \int \int d \mathbf  p d \mathbf q \ e^{-\beta H}$$

Therefore, you will write

$$p(\mathbf p ,\mathbf q)= \frac{e^{-\beta H}}{\int \int d \mathbf p d \mathbf q \ e^{-\beta H}} = \frac{e^{-\beta H}} {Z h^3}$$

In principle, nothing prevents you from defining a dimensional partition function $Z'$:

$$Z' \equiv \int \int d \mathbf  p d \mathbf q \ e^{-\beta H}$$

and writing

$$p(\mathbf p ,\mathbf q)= \frac{e^{-\beta H}}{\int \int d \mathbf p d \mathbf q \ e^{-\beta H}} = \frac{e^{-\beta H}} {Z'}$$

So, in the end, it it is just a matter of being coherent, but you can in principle use the notation that you prefer.

Comment: *Therefore, you will write*

$$p(\mathbf p ,\mathbf q)= \frac{e^{-\beta H}}{\int \int d \mathbf p d \mathbf q \ e^{-\beta H}} = \frac{e^{-\beta H}} {Z h^3}\ .$$

Yes, this is what a started off my question with; I already have the result. My question: other than to make the integral 1 and getting the correct units, what reason is there to divide by $h^3$ in the final expression? we divide by the phase-space integral by $h^3$ in order to get the number of states. Why do we need to correct for this $h^3$, **other than to make the integral 1 or getting the units correct?**

Comment: The only reason is that you want $Z$ to be dimensionless. There is no deeper reason, really.